# Android: NotSerializableException BasicNameValuePair

Tags: android, serialization

I have the following problem: the save-procedure below raises the exception "java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair":

```
fos = getBaseContext().openFileOutput("merkzettel", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
os.writeObject(merkList);
os.close();
```

"merkList" is an `ArrayList<Product>`, whereby product is a class like:

```
public class MerkFinProduct implements Serializable {
   LinkedList<BasicNameValuePair> test;
   String Id;   
   String name;
   Date date;
   String urlPic;
   String response;
       //...
}
```

According to [link to BasicNameValuePair](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html) BasicNameValuePair implements the Serializable-Interface. So I really have no idea, what is the problem here...

Maybe some one of you can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are using the Android version of [BasicNameValuePair](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html) and it's not Seriaizable